# in React, I want to keep state after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I want to keep state after refreshing page. I tried to use localStorage but every time I refresh page it keeps clearing data.

```
function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState()
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

  const items = [
    {
      name: "xx99 mark || headphones",
      description: "This huge e-commerce challenge will provide an incredible test for your front-end skills. Once you're done, you'll have an amazing project to add to your portfolio!",
      img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/205926/pexels-photo-205926.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
      price: 159
    },
    {
      name: "xx99 mark | headphones",
      description: "This huge e-commerce challenge will provide an incredible test for your front-end skills. Once you're done, you'll have an amazing project to add to your portfolio!",
      img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/610945/pexels-photo-610945.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
      price: 120,
    },
    {
      name: "x99 mark || headphones",
      description: "This huge e-commerce challenge will provide an incredible test for your front-end skills. Once you're done, you'll have an amazing project to add to your portfolio!",
      img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3945667/pexels-photo-3945667.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
      price: 400
    },
  ]

  localStorage.setItem("cart-item", JSON.stringify(cart))
  
  return (
    <>
      <userContext.Provider value={{ selected, setSelected, items, cart, setCart }}>

        <BrowserRouter>
          <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/headphones' element={<Headphones />} />
            <Route path='/speakrs' element={<Speakers />} />
            <Route path='/earphones' element={<Earphones />} />
            <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </userContext.Provider>
    </>

  );
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code that loads the items from local storage?

Comment: With the code provided, what line do you think loads the cart?

Comment: ```const handleCartAdd = (selectedItem) => {
    setCart([...cart, selectedItem])
  }
  <button className='see-full-btn' onClick={() => handleCartAdd(selected)}>add to cart</button>```

Comment: NOT add to cart,  load the cart.  None of the code your showing loads the cart from `localeStorage`, hint:  You should have some code that calls `localStorage.getItem`..

Comment: we all had the same story, after seeing that localstorage is slow or buggy we begin to use REDUX and then later FLUX, welcome aboard React Native

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the items are saved in the local storage in the first place?

Run your app -> go to console -> application -> local storage

Can you see any data there?

Comment: > yes I can see it

Comment: As i can see in the code snippet, you are saving the cart variable which is an empty array, have you tried saving the items array

Comment: its not empty. I am adding items in it from another route

Comment: I know problem it that state is refreshing after page reload because of that localstorage.setitem line is starts working again and clears storage

Comment: I could not find solution

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code with me to asses you with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
```

to

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState(localStorage.getItem("cart-item") ?  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart-item")) : [])
```

should work fine.